# Opening and reading a file in Qt

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt5

I am trying to use the menu bar to open a file (hardcoded) when 'File|Open' is clicked. The file should append to and display each line. My function is not finding the file. So after I click open I am getting back 'trace.txt cannot be found'. I have the file saved in the same directory as the rest of the project files. I am wondering if I haven't opened the file properly? Can anyone have a look at my code and see if you're catching an error that I am not?

```
void MainWindow::readFile(){
    infoLabel->setText(tr("Invoked <b>File|Open</b>"));
    QString filename="trace.txt";
    QFile file(filename);
    if(!file.exists()){
        qDebug() << "File <i>cannot</i> be found "<<filename;
    }else{
        qDebug() << filename<<" Opening...";
    }
    QString line;
    textEdit->clear();
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        while (!stream.atEnd()){
            line = stream.readLine();
            textEdit->setText(textEdit->toPlainText()+"0x"+line+"\n");
            qDebug() << "line: "<<line;
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

UPDATE: 
I changed the QFile object to the direct path and that found the file. On the other hand, I am reading it in an infinite loop, which never makes it to the textEdit and continually outputs to the debugger. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the directory with your "project files" the same as your built executable? Try to put it in the same directory as the executable or just put the complete path into the QFile constructor.

Comment: Print out the string returned by QDir::currentPath(); I bet it's different from the path where the trace.txt file is located at.

Comment: To put it in the constructor, would I put it in as two arguments? One being the string variable 'filename' as I have written above and the other being the full path?

Answer (score 2):

Use current or currentPath() to see with which directory you are working.
See this example to understand the current directory:

```
QFile file;
QDir::setCurrent("/tmp");
file.setFileName("readme.txt");
QDir::setCurrent("/home");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);      // opens "/home/readme.txt" under Unix
```

From http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#QFile